# SVG translate with em as unit?

Tags: svg

Is there a way to use em as unit for SVG translations? As in

```xml
<rect height="10em" width="10em" transform="translate(0em, 10em)"
 style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:black/>
```

The rectangle does not translate in Firefox, unless I remove the em as unit.

Comment: Apologies, I did not highlight the code snippet as code snippet so it did not display.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that transformation units--as with `<path>` commands--must all be in user space. However, I am posting this as a comment instead of an answer because I cannot currently find a spec confirming this.

Comment: More information: read the section labeled "Tranforms"[sic] here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Feb/0550.html

Answer (score 19):

You can sort of do this if you wrap the element(s) you want to translate in a new coordinate system:

```
<svg>
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
    <rect height="10" width="10" transform="translate(0, 10)" .../>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Another option if you only need translations and use elements that have x and y attributes (or equivalent) is to use those instead, like this:

```
<rect x="0" y="10em" height="10em" width="10em" 
 style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:black/>
```

A new specification for [transforms in CSS/SVG](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transforms/) is currently being worked on, and it will indeed allow units in translations, see [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transforms/#svg-syntax).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, not;

The specs [explicitly allow for *user units*](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units) - that correspond to CSS units and default to pixel units when otherwise not specified - to be applied for coordinates, while translations are meant to be used with floating point numbers exclusively as defined by the [SVGMatrix interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do if you're creating the rect with javascript is retrieve the font size of a parent element and convert the em value to px.

Using jQuery:

```
var one_em = +$("#parent").css("font-size").replace("px", "");
$("#parent").append("<rect transform=translate(0," + (10*one_em) + ") .../>")
```